# Calculate column value count as a bar plot in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, bar-chart

I have time series data and want to see total number of Septic (1) and Non-septic (0) patients in the **SepsisLabel** column. The Non-septic patients don't have entries of '1'. While the Septic patients have first 'Zeros (0)' then it changes to '1' means it now becomes septic. The data looks like this:

| HR | SBP | DBP | SepsisLabel | Gender | P_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 92 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 98 | 115 | 85 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 93 | 125 | 75 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 95 | 130 | 90 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 93 | 125 | 75 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 95 | 130 | 90 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 93 | 125 | 75 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 95 | 130 | 90 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 102 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 109 | 115 | 75 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 94 | 135 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 97 | 100 | 70 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 85 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 88 | 115 | 75 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 93 | 125 | 85 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 78 | 130 | 90 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 115 | 140 | 110 | 1 | 1 | 4 |

Here, there are 3 Septic patients (P_ID = 1, 3, 4) and 2 Non-septic patients (P_ID = 0, 2). I want to plot this number as a bar plot. So, I manually did this using the following code:

[image: pic]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
sepsis = ['Non-Septic patients', 'Septic patients']
count = [2, 3]
ax.bar(sepsis, count)

ax.set_title("Septic and Non-septic patient count in the dataset", y = 1, fontsize = 15)
ax.set_xlabel('Patients', fontsize = 12)
ax.set_ylabel('Count', fontsize = 12)

for bars in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(bars)
ax.margins(y=0.1)  
plt.show()
```

1. However, I don't want to manually calculate the septic and non-septic patient count as the data I have is very large. This is just the dummy data. I know I must use P_ID column but not sure how.
2. Second thing I want to plot is Out of these septic and non-septic patients, how many are Male (1) and Female (0) based on the **Gender** column. I want something like this graph:

[image: pic2]

`****Update****`

Using `drop_duplicates` keeps only first row by default. So, the septic patient which has initially `0s` then it changes to `1`, there arise problem for them. Using the code only take first row even the patient is septic. Thus total number of septic patients drops, while number of non-septic patients increases, which shouldn't. Is it possible to keep only those rows in septic patients where `0` changes to `1`? So, all septic patients will have `1` in SepsisLabel in their first row instead of `0`. This will give the correct number of septic patients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1) use `np.where`. For 2), you can use `seaborn` for the second purpose:

```
dedup = df.groupby('P_ID')[['SepsisLabel', 'Gender']].max().reset_index()

dedup['SepticType'] = np.where(dedup.SepsisLabel, 'Septic', 'NonSeptic')
sns.countplot(data=dedup, x='SepticType', hue='Gender')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: But if I don't know what IDs are Septic and Non-septic, how I can use `isin`? Because as I said in the question it is the dummy data. So, I know there are 3 septic patients. But on the real data, I don't want to calculate this manually for1.5 million rows.

Comment: You already have the answer, `df.P_ID.isin(...)` with `df.SepsisLabel`? I also update the answer with the correct code, just not the correct image.

Comment: I got this error. `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. I used the exact code but just renamed the dataframe

Comment: I was just passing by and decided to give this 2 lines solution a try, but I got this error: "IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)."

Comment: @Drakax strange. Updated answer should work now.

Comment: @QuangHoang this is the same code I've tested earlier. I've started over again from scratch but still get the same error. DataFrame  and Data both look good. The result of my "septic_types" is "array(['NonSeptic', 'Septic', 'NonSeptic', 'Septic', 'Septic'],
      dtype='<U9')" which is correct too. Weird.

Comment: @QuangHoang The code is good, however there was a thing I forgot to mention while posting the question. Can you please check it ?

Comment: @Zaif updated.  Once a `P_ID` has `1` in SepsisLabel, it's labelled as Septic.

Comment: That's great. Muchas gracias amigo :)